# How to install wget with --debug option?

Tags: homebrew, wget

I try to install `wget` with the `--debug` option.

https://discourse.brew.sh/t/how-to-install-wget-with-debug-support/1672

But the following does not work. Does anybody know how to install wget with the `--debug` option of `wget`?

```
$ brew reinstall wget --with-debug
Usage: brew reinstall [options] formula

Uninstall and then install formula using the same options it was originally
installed with, plus any appended brew formula options.

Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will then be run for
the reinstalled formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.

  -d, --debug                      If brewing fails, open an interactive
                                   debugging session with access to IRB or a
                                   shell inside the temporary build directory.
  -s, --build-from-source          Compile formula from source even if a
                                   bottle is available.
  -i, --interactive                Download and patch formula, then open a
                                   shell. This allows the user to run
                                   ./configure --help and otherwise
                                   determine how to turn the software package
                                   into a Homebrew package.
      --force-bottle               Install from a bottle if it exists for the
                                   current or newest version of macOS, even if
                                   it would not normally be used for
                                   installation.
      --keep-tmp                   Retain the temporary files created during
                                   installation.
  -f, --force                      Install without checking for previously
                                   installed keg-only or non-migrated
                                   versions.
  -v, --verbose                    Print the verification and postinstall
                                   steps.
      --display-times              Print install times for each formula at the
                                   end of the run.
  -q, --quiet                      Suppress any warnings.
  -h, --help                       Show this message.
Error: invalid option: --with-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `brew edit wget` and add there `--enable-debug`, save, then run `brew install --build-from-source wget`